# In the Wolfram Curated Data Is "Missing[NotApplicable]" Somehow Special?

Tags: curated-data, filtering, missing

I have a simple two dimensional table, but I can't seem to `Select[]`, or `Cases[]` match the data when the second column is `_Missing`.  In the sample from my table below the Anquilla data shows `Missing["NotApplicable"]` but it still shows a value?  How do I properly delete the fields with second column marked `Missing` like this?

Here is a sample of my data:

```
Afghanistan 0.221735per person
Albania 0.966919per person
Algeria 0.85049per person
American Samoa  0.0411192per person
Andorra 0.75127per person
Angola  0.318379per person
Anguilla    Missing[NotApplicable] (1/16086per person)
Antigua and Barbuda 1.49616per person
Argentina   1.11193per person
Armenia 0.98433per person
Aruba   1.10711per person
Australia   0.941166per person
Austria 1.27968per person
Azerbaijan  0.679035per person
Bahamas 0.996959per person
Bahrain 1.03725per person
Bangladesh  0.285458per person
Barbados    1.47237per person
Belarus 0.858297per person
Belgium 1.0905per person
```

Answer (score 3):

I assume the information you asked for is calculated by calculating the ratio of two or more quantities. It looks like one of these is missing in the case of Anguilla.

`DeleteMissing` would be the most focused function for your goal, but it needs a level specification here since `Missing` does not occur here as a simple element but is part of an expression with `Times`. The following will do:

```
DeleteMissing[{1, 1, x, 2 Missing[1], 3, y, 9, y}, 1, Infinity]

(*==> {1, 1, x, 3, y, 9, y} *)
```

Two level specifications here. '1' indicates to look at level 1 in the list, and `Infinity` means that we should look at any depth in the expressions we find there.

For Mathematica version lower than 10 something like

```
DeleteCases[{1, 1, x, 2 Missing[1], 3, y, 9, y}, _?(MemberQ[#, _Missing, Infinity] &)]
```

would do the job.